# JQuery Issue - trying to loop through an array via cookie that has stored form data using serializeArray

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through an array with form data used in a cookie. It's not working for some reason, when I alert(mycookies[i]) it's returning a value of undefined. When I alert(mycookies) it returns the array values.

```
   var formCapture = $.param($("#portalOptionsForm").serializeArray());

   $.cookie('formRestore', formCapture );

   $('a.restoreCookie').click(function ()

    {
      var cookie = $.cookie('formRestore')
      var mycookies = $.cookie('formRestore').split("&");


      for(var i = 0; i < mycookies.length; i++) 
        {
        mycookies[i].slice(mycookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1 ,mycookies.length);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what your looking for:

```
var formCapture = $.param($("#portalOptionsForm").serializeArray());

$.cookie('formRestore', JSON.stringify(formCapture));

$('a.restoreCookie').click(function ()
{
  var myCookieData = JSON.parse($.cookie('formRestored'));
});
```

Then look at the values of 'var myCookieData' - using something like:

```
console.log(myCookieData);
```